# Strategy for watermarking images

Tags: php, image, image-processing, watermark

Currently when users are uploading images to my website, I only store watermarked images. Should I also save the plain images? Or should I possible save the plain images and then, on request, display the image with a dynamically generated (PHP) watermark?

What are your preferences?
And if I generate the images on the fly with PHP, should I be concerned about performance of those images?

Comment: Show the watermark on the way out, else your stuck with images which have watermarks, if for some reason you want to allow no watermark you cant :s

Comment: @LawrenceCherone what about loading times? I am using PHP's image-functions. Would that cause a significant delay?

Comment: Unless your images are in 8k you shouldn't see a noticeable performance hit.

Comment: If your site is mainly images, you should install imagick, as it will produce nicer images and maybe faster then gd, and using a package like [intervention](http://image.intervention.io/api/insert), should be as good as it gets.

Comment: why even show use watermarks if you display other people's images? and the only person that can tell you if you shoudl store watermarked images is you because you are the only person that knows what you need... also please read [ask]. Your question is off-topic.

Comment: I would save both as server space is not that expensive these days. You can get imagemagick or GD to add a watermark "on the fly" if you want. I havn't checked but that may reveal the path to the original un watermarked image. If it was my own images I would not save both but if you do not own the originals and want to change the size or watermark you could regenerate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many of current photography-cms software packages use GD and also ImageMagick.

You can upload a high or medium resolution image, and have a script like GD generate the low-res web version, including watermark.

unless it is a very large amount of very high res images, performance should not be a concern on current hardware.

(if you would like help with the php/gd part, you could ask another question, as this one is not related to that)